# Overriding Spree Assets

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, assets, spree

I'm using spree 2.1.5, rails 4.0.2, sass-rails 4.0.0.

The spree documentation at http://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/asset.html indicates using the vendor/assets/stylesheets folder. However, examples I see of spree stylesheet overrides on Github and from other google search show many people using the app/assets/stylesheets folder.

Is it best to override spree styles in the folder my_store/app/assets/stylesheets? Or my_store/vendor/assets/stylesheets?

Comment: consider marking my answer as correct if it was helpful to you

Comment: Where you did put finally ?

Answer (score 5):

I put my css in the "normal" place - in app/assets/stylesheets, and nothing changed.  I put my css in the  vendor/assets/stylesheets folder, and they were applied.

Working with Spree very un-like working with "Rails" - though spree is running on a rails server.  The process starts with, "Where are the files?" and gets more bizarre from there.  This is why I am abandoning it for a custom solution. In many cases, it would take longer to learn how to modify/customize Spree, than to write a new solution (for the parts of it we actually need) from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

#### Update:

Unlike stated in my original answer, Spree will **not** even evaluate stuff in `app/assets/stylesheets` and style customizations need to be made in `vendor/assets/stylesheets`, e.g. in

`vendor/assets/stylesheets/spree/frontend/all.css`

TlmaK0 is perfectly right pointing this out.

---

Quoting from http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html:

> Pipeline assets can be placed inside an application in one of three
>   locations: app/assets, lib/assets or vendor/assets.
>
> - app/assets is for assets that are owned by the application, such as custom images, JavaScript files or stylesheets.
> - lib/assets is for your own libraries' code that doesn't really fit into the scope of the application or those libraries which are shared
>     across applications.
> - vendor/assets is for assets that are owned by outside entities, such as code for JavaScript plugins and CSS frameworks.

Short: You probably want to put your override stuff into `app/assets/stylesheets`.

Comment: Spree uses vendor/assets/stylesheets, changes on app/assets/stylesheets are ignored

Answer (score 0):

Normally all the code for font-end and back-end for spree loads into to your rvm as other gems, you can override them by creating `decorators` folder into app(same as like models, controllers). Or you can put the file at the same location(but this is not right solution) and can make the change like `mainapp/app/views/spree/admin/shared/_header.html.erb`

For decorators example say I want to  override spree's `products_controller` I will put it at `decorators/products_controller_decorator.rb`

```
 Spree::ProductsController.class_eval do
   #mychanges
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

Export all views to app/views with:

`rails generate spree:frontend:copy_views`

This will generate all frontend views in app/views to override it.

Edit `app/views/spree/shared/_head.html.erb` and add:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'screen' %>
```

to include app/assets/stylesheets folder.